# How to write a rule for reading two lines using rply's parser?

Tags: python, list, parsing

I'm having issues writing a rule that can read more than one line of code in my parser.

when I print one line, the output is fine, however I get an error if I try to print two lines.

```
raise ParsingError(None, lookahead.getsourcepos())
rply.errors.ParsingError: (None, SourcePosition(idx=12, lineno=2, colno=1))
```

I'm following a solution posted at ([How to parse multiple line code using RPLY library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60016733/how-to-parse-multiple-line-code-using-rply-library)) however I don't think I'm understanding the response correctly. I changed my ast.py code twice and got two different errors

parse_gen.py

```
        @self.pg.production('expression : PRINT OPEN_PAREN expression CLOSE_PAREN')
        @self.pg.production('program : expression')
        @self.pg.production('program : program expression')

        def program(p):
            return Program(p)
            return Print(p[2])
```

ast.py

```
class Program():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def eval(self):
        self.value.eval()
```

error 1

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

ast.py

```
class Program():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def eval(self):
        x = self.value
        for i in x:
            return i.eval()
```

error 2

```
AttributeError: 'Token' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

I also tried adding a for loop for p in the program function, but that also brings up the second error.

Answer (score 1):

I guess one important thing you're missing is the rule by which RPLY decides which non-terminal represents the input you want to parse. This is the "start non-terminal", and it's really simple: RPLY (like almost all parser generators) just uses the *first* non-terminal that it sees defined.

In your case, that will be `expression`, so you'll get a parser which parses (one) expression. It seems clear that what you wanted was `program`, which parses an entire program (of multiple expressions).

It's true that the RPLY documentation is pathetically lacking in details, although the documentation it refers to (PLY and Bison, as I recall) is more elaborate, and all of these generators use the same parsing algorithm (by default). To use RPLY you need to do more research. But that's the price you pay for selecting a poorly-documented product; you could use a different parser generator.

Comment: I feel like OP is missing significantly more than that, including how productions are associated to functions (why should parsing a print statement call the `program` function?), what `p` contains (`Program(p)` is clearly not giving `Program` the type of list it expects, even when `p` is the result of one of `program`'s productions rather than `expression`) and why having two consecutive `return` statements isn't useful.

Comment: @sepp2k: You're probably right, but the ordering of productions has featured in about three consecutive attempts to solve this particular problem. I don't feel like SO is the place to write a full manual on how to use a parser generator, so I did the best I could in the space I was prepared to dedicate to it. I do feel like there is a tendency to grab for the latest shiniest immature product without considering whether the documentation is close to adequate, which feeds into the historic failure of OSS to provide good documentation in early stages of development (and sometimes later).

Comment: @sepp2k: Another thing that I keep biting off my tongue: Learn to program before you try to write a programming language :-)